# Get value from anonymous block inside a procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have created a stored procedure which calls a function which returns boolean.

We are getting the schema name the function is under at run time, so we are creating the statement as a string by concatenation, and executing the function in an anonymous block dynamically.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE usp_proc
(
        variable declarations
)
as
var1 varchar2(50);
var2 varchar2(50);
var3 varchar3(50);
begin
    execute immediate
        'declare result boolean ; ConversionFactor number; res varchar2(10); begin  result:= '||schemaname||'fn_name('''||var1||''', '''||var2||''',ConversionFactor,'''||var3||''');'||
                    ' if(result=False) then res:=''False'';'||
                    ' ELSE res:=''True''; END IF; end;';

    stmt:='select Weight*ConversionFactor  from table'
       Open cur for stmt;   
    END;
```

I need to use the `ConversionFactor` variable outside the anonymous block. How can I gets its value to use later in the procedure?

Comment: You can directly call the function inside BEGIN block of the procedure. No need to use the dynamic sql.

Comment: @SabinJose - the schema the function is under isn't known at compile time though (if I'm reading this right), so it does have to be called dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than define `ConversionFactor` as a local variable inside your dynamic PL/SQL block, you can declare it in your procedure and [pass it as an `OUT` bind variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS1224). You can get the `res` value back the same way too. Your `var1`, `var2` and `var3` values can/should be passed as bind variables as well, rather than concatenating them into the call.

Demo using an anonymous block instead of a procedure, as yours has some other things wrong anyway, and a dummy function in the specified schema:

```
declare
  var1 varchar2(50);
  var2 varchar2(50);
  var3 varchar2(50);
  schemaname varchar2(30);
  res varchar2(5);
  ConversionFactor number;
begin
  schema := 'SOME_SCHEMA';
  -- also assign values to var1, var2 and var, presumably

  execute immediate
    'declare result boolean;'
      || 'begin'
      || ' result := '||schemaname||'.fn_name(:var1, :var2, :ConversionFactor, :var3);'
      || ' :res := case when result then ''True'' else ''False'' end;'
      || 'end;'
  using var1, var2, out ConversionFactor, var3, out res;

  dbms_output.put_line('Got result: ' || res);
  dbms_output.put_line('Got ConversionFactor: ' || ConversionFactor);
end;
/

Got result: True
Got ConversionFactor: 42

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Note the `out ConversionFactor`, and the `out res`, so mark them as `OUT` bind variables. The others are left to default to `IN`. (I've also added a missing period between the schema and function names).